# How do I install remastersys?

Tags: remastersys

I was following instruction from http://www.remastersys.com/ubuntu.html to install remastersys in my system. On `apt-get update` always get error that the could not find correct structure of URL.

Any help?

Comment: what is the best option to make a live and installable CD of a running ubuntu system

Comment: remastersys.com is gone so none of these instructions that mention it will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its happening because there is a deb-src line in your /etc/apt/sources.list file. Either remove or comment this out:-

```
deb-src http://www.remastersys.com/ubuntu precise main
```

Comment: It's outdated and doesn't work now.

Answer (score 8):

**You can install Remastersys in Ubuntu 12.04**

As root - issue

```
'sudo su'
```

in the terminal window prior to the following command.

```
wget -O - http://www.remastersys.com/ubuntu/remastersys.gpg.key | apt-key add -

sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Add the following line

```
#Remastersys Precise
deb http://www.remastersys.com/ubuntu precise main
```

Now open the terminal and type

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install remastersys remastersys-gui
```

**Here is the screenshot**

[image]

**Source:** http://www.remastersys.com/ubuntu.html

Comment: Your "as root, issue sudo su" is a bit redundant as sudo brings you to root and the "as root" part assumes the user is already running as root.

Answer (score 5):

Two things - one; I believe they've started up work on Remastersys again.

Two; Relinux seems nice and has a purpose, but it is NOT the same as Remastersys. When it comes to creating installable live CD clones of a system with its installed software, it fails miserably.   With Relinux, you get the base OS, plus whatever packages you include via Relinux.  Very nice, to be sure, but a far cry from Remastersys's simple elegance of just grabbing and wrapping up everything exactly as it is for your later live-disc amusement.

Relinux may be "better" at making a particular distro, but FAILS MISERABLY if what you want is a live image of your current system.

Answer (score 2):

-Remastersys is no longer supported, actually-. There is a new project, [Relinux](https://launchpad.net/relinux), that aims to be better than Remastersys ever was, while allowing you to do the same thing (remaster your system).

See this blog for full details: https://relinuxkit.wordpress.com/

Comment: -1 ,Because Remastersys still supported :)

Comment: remastersys was never official, but it generally worked pretty well. So, i suppose it was 'never supported' by ubuntu. It *does* still seem to work [and the dev seems to want to sort out people who think its dead](http://www.remastersys.com/forums/index.php?topic=2105.15). Inaccurate as such, but i'll let it pass cause i've learnt of a new tool ;p

Answer (score 2):

Since the web site   http://www.remastersys.com   now seems to have disappeared permanently, the above instructions don't work as they rely on downloads from the website.

This is what I did to get a copy of Remastersys 3.0.4-2 running on Ubuntu 14.04.

1. Go to this website: http://www.filewatcher.com and search for, then download the following files:

   remastersys_3.0.4-2_all.deb
   remastersys-gui_3.0.4-1_i386.deb  (32-bit)
   remastersys-gui_3.0.4-1_amd64.deb (64-bit)
2. Install as follows:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install plymouth-x11       
   sudo dpkg -i remastersys_3.0.4-2_all.deb  
   sudo dpkg -i remastersys-gui_3.0.4-1_i386.deb     (32 bit)
   sudo dpkg -i remastersys-gui_3.0.4-1_amd_64.deb   (64 bit)
   ```
3. If you have unmet dependencies run:

   ```
   sudo apt-get -f install
   ```
4. Launch Remastersys as follows:

   ```
   sudo remastersys-gui
   ```

   This will bring up the usual Remastersys GUI menu.

Answer (score 1):

On 140214 Fragadelic posted in the Forums that Remastersys for 12.04 and 12.10 would remain at the repo for another year.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2102312&page=3&highlight=usb

Answer (score 1):

Since the web site http://www.remastersys.com now seems to have disappeared permanently, the above instructions don't work as they rely on downloads from the website.

This is what I did to get a copy of Remastersys 3.0.4-2 running on Ubuntu 14.04

1. Go to this website: http://www.filewatcher.com

Search for, then download the following files:

remastersys_3.0.4-2_all.deb

remastersys-gui_3.0.4-1_i386.deb (32 bit)

remastersys-gui_3.0.4-1_amd64.deb (64 bit)

2. Install as follows:

   sudo apt-get install plymouth-x11

   sudo dpkg -i remastersys_3.0.4-2_all.deb

   sudo dpkg -i remastersys-gui_3.0.4-1_i386.deb (32 bit)

   sudo dpkg -i remastersys-gui_3.0.4-1_amd_64.deb (64 bit)
3. If you have un-met dependencies run:

   sudo apt-get -f install
4. Launch Remastersys as follows:

   sudo remastersys-gui

This will bring up the usual Remastersys GUI menu.

Hope this is useful. 
TLG

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to drudge this up again, but we are planning on forking remastersys. For now we haven't made any changes, but we are preparing to keep it going. We are going to change the name. I just installed it from this source on xubuntu 14.04:

http://www.remastersys.com/ubuntu/pool/main/r/remastersys-gui/

It did have a dependency of plymouth-x11.

so
download:

remastersys-gui_3.0.4-1_amd64.deb

```
sudo apt-get install plymouth-x11       
sudo dpkg -i remastersys-gui_3.0.4-1_amd64.deb
```

If you don't see it in your menu, you can start it from a terminal by running this command

```
sudo remastersys-gui
```

Keep in mind this is all stock we have not made any changes to it yet, but I have tested this and it works on my Xubuntu 14.04 laptop

We will be changing the name soon, and will try and get it back into the main repos.

Comment: that link, and those files, are gone.

Answer (score -1):

### Minimal Ubuntu i386 32 bits installation with apt repositories.

I've managed to install remastersys on a
**Minimal Ubuntu i386 32 bits.**

---

**1. Adding remastersys repository as Eliah and Tachyons posted:**

You can install Remastersys in Ubuntu 12.04

As root - issue

`sudo su`

in the terminal window prior to the following command.

`wget -O - http://www.remastersys.com/ubuntu/remastersys.gpg.key | apt-key add -`

`sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`

Add the following line

`#Remastersys Precise deb http://www.remastersys.com/ubuntu precise main`

---

**2. Installing remastersys and its dependencies :**

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install kpartx-boot kpartx kpartx cryptsetup cryptsetup-bin dmraid libdmraid1.0.0.rc16 kpartx-boot ecryptfs-utils libecryptfs0 libnss3-1d lvm2 libdevmapper-event1.02.1 watershed ubuntu-drivers-common python3-xkit bogl-bterm ncurses-term samba-common keyutils libvte-common libparted-fs-resize0 ubiquity-artwork-2.20.0 ubiquity-casper rdate ecryptfs-utils cryptsetup python3-icu python3-pam archdetect-deb dpkg-repack apt-clone dmraid btrfs-tools ubuntu-drivers-common lvm2 localechooser-data cifs-utils libvte9 mtools syslinux-common ubiquity bogl-bterm  memtest86+ casper libdebian-installer4 ubiquity-frontend-debconf user-setup syslinux xresprobe  squashfs-tools remastersys remastersys-gui`

---

***Thanks*** to all you people who have been working within these projects!

Comment: remastersys.com is gone.

Answer (score -1):

UPDATE 05.01.2015

The link I provide in this and other instructions in step 2 does not work anymore. However, I had downloaded the Remastersys files before the website shut down and they can be installed perfectly through Ubuntu Software Center. !! I am not sure if the files are available in Ubuntu Software Center, but if you have them on your computer, they can be installed through it.

This set of instructions helped me install and run successfully remastersys on Ubuntu 14.04.1 32bit and also successfully create and use a bootable flash drive with the custom iso I made.

A note: flash drive works unless you manually made an upgrade of the kernel for some reason before.

1. Press Ctrl-Alt-T and run

   ```
   sudo apt-get install plymouth-x11
   ```
2. Go to [this](http://www.remastersys.com/ubuntu/pool/main/r/remastersys-gui/) link and download `remastersys` version for 32bit or 64bit system

   **IMPORTANT**: I downloaded version 3.0.4-1 i386 and it WORKS I checked 3.0.2- version and it doesn't work.
3. Open Programs and Updates (search in Dash or in the System's parametres)
4. In Programs and Updates, go to Other tab and press Add...
5. Copy/paste this

   ```
   deb http://www.remastersys.com/ubuntu precise main
   ```

   and press OK
6. Now look for two lines with "www.remastersys.com/" in the list you can find on the Other tab and make sure you check both boxes. Enter a password if you are asked to.
7. Press Ctrl-Alt-T and run

   ```
   sudo apt-get install remastersys-gui
   ```
8. To open remastersys-gui, you always need root privileges. So do it in the terminal (Ctrl-Alt-T)

   ```
   sudo remastersys-gui
   ```

Comment: remastersys.com is gone.